# Create columns from column values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data in Excel:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+----------+
| Name                        | Category           | Number   |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+----------+
| Alex                        | Portret            |        3 |
| Alex                        | Other              |        2 |
| Serge                       | Animals            |        1 |
| Serge                       | Portret            |        4 |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

And I want to transform it to:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| Name      | Portret   | Other | Animals |
+-----------+-----------+-------+---------+
| Alex      | 3         |     2 |   0     |
| Serge     | 4         |     0 |   1     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

How can I do it in MS Excel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pivot table for that

Take a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx